# Recursive rsync over ssh, include only one file extension

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to rsync files over ssh from a server to my machine. Files are in various subdirectories, but I only want to keep the ones that match a certain pattern (IE *blah*.txt). I have done extensive googling and searching on stackoverflow, and I've tried just about every permutation of --include and --excludes that have been suggested. No matter what I try, rsync grabs all files.
Just as an example of one of my attempts, I have used:
`rsync -avze 'ssh' --include='*blah*.txt' --exclude='*' myusername@myserver.com:/path/top/files/directory /path/to/local/directory`

To troubleshoot, I tried this command:
`rsync -avze 'ssh' --exclude='*' myusername@myserver.com:/path/top/files/directory /path/to/local/directory`
expecting it to not copy anything, but it still grabbed all of the files.

I am using rsync version 2.6.9 on OSX.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've been struggling with this for quite a while.

Comment: Just FYI, `rsync` has a `--dry-run` flag.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a solution, with a caveat. Here is the working command:
`rsync -vre 'ssh' --prune-empty-dirs --include='*/' --include='*blah*.txt' --exclude='*' user@server.com:/path/to/server/files /path/to/local/files`

However! If I type this into my command line directly, it works. If I save it to a file, myfile.txt, and I try `cat myfile.txt` it no longer works! This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why would you "cat" a file to run it?

Answer (score -1):

OSX follows BSD style rsync

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rsync&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html

-C, --cvs-exclude
          This  is a useful shorthand for excluding a broad range of files
          that you often don't want to transfer between systems. It uses a
          similar  algorithm  to  CVS  to  determine  if  a file should be
          ignored.

```
      The exclude list is initialized to exclude the  following  items
      (these  initial items are marked as perishable -- see the FILTER
      RULES section):

         RCS  SCCS  CVS  CVS.adm   RCSLOG   cvslog.*   tags   TAGS
         .make.state  .nse_depinfo *~ #* .#* ,* _$* *$ *.old *.bak
         *.BAK *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o *.obj *.so  *.exe
         *.Z *.elc *.ln core .svn/ .git/ .bzr/

      then,  files  listed in a $HOME/.cvsignore are added to the list
      and any files listed in the CVSIGNORE environment variable  (all
      cvsignore names are delimited by whitespace).

      Finally, any file is ignored if it is in the same directory as a
      .cvsignore file and matches one of the patterns listed  therein.
      Unlike rsync's filter/exclude files, these patterns are split on
      whitespace.  See the cvs(1) manual for more information.

      If you're combining -C with your own --filter rules, you  should
      note that these CVS excludes are appended at the end of your own
      rules, regardless of where the -C was  placed  on  the  command-
      line.  This makes them a lower priority than any rules you spec-
      ified explicitly.  If  you  want  to  control  where  these  CVS
      excludes  get  inserted  into your filter rules, you should omit
      the -C as a command-line option and use a combination of  --fil-
      ter=:C  and  --filter=-C  (either  on  your  command-line  or by
      putting the ":C" and "-C" rules into a  filter  file  with  your
      other rules).  The first option turns on the per-directory scan-
      ning for the .cvsignore file.  The second option does a one-time
      import of the CVS excludes mentioned above.

   -f, --filter=RULE
      This  option allows you to add rules to selectively exclude cer-
      tain files from the list of files to  be  transferred.  This  is
      most useful in combination with a recursive transfer.

      You  may use as many --filter options on the command line as you
      like to build up the list of files to exclude.   If  the  filter
      contains whitespace, be sure to quote it so that the shell gives
      the rule to rsync as a single argument.   The  text  below  also
      mentions  that  you  can  use an underscore to replace the space
      that separates a rule from its arg.

      See the FILTER RULES section for detailed  information  on  this
      option.
```